# How to get current LI text if class name is same for all LI ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am facing problem to get LI text coz i have 10 LI list and all LI class name is same. when i try to get text by using class name or id i get last text.

this is my code
`<ul>
<li class="a">text</li>`.
text1
`.<li class="a">text2</li>`.
text3`.
<li class="a">text4</li>`

please help me how i will get data.

Comment: You want all `li` text? What should be the output according to you? Also your HTML seems to be invalid.

Comment: Actually sir i have generated LI by using AJAX. but when i use onclick function on Li  so its not working. i want get li data on onclick function but onclick not working after ajax li load.

Comment: Where is the non-working script?

Comment: sir this is my simple javascript function


function set_item(item,item1) {
 alert("sdfsf"); 
 
}

<li onclick="set_item(a,b)" class="a">text</a> 
<li onclick="set_item(c,d)" class="a">texta</a>

Comment: is your onclick function in a loop?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Sir this onclick function working proper but when i load this by ajax it is not working

Comment: Post your whole code, or a non-working demo atleast.

Comment: Post more code and browser name on which you are trying...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you are looking for. But from my understanding you want to know which element is clicked.

so i think this might work
https://jsfiddle.net/a2y1n7p9/

Just use a selfinvoking function.

```
var liElements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
  liElements[i].onclick = function(i){
   return function() {
     alert(i + ' Element');
   }  
  }(i); 
}
```